# The program can't start because cygwin1.dll is missing... in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, dll, cygwin, exe, eclipse-cdt

I've had Eclipse for Java on my computer for a few years, and decided to install the CDT and learn C. I installed both `MinGW` and `Cygwin` and the CDT detects and tries to use them when I make a new project.

I choose `File > New C++ Project` and choose `Hello World C++ Project` and the `CygwinGCC` toolchain. I name the project "asdf" and hit "Build Debug" in the toolbar. The compiler completes without error. I hit Run and nothing happens.

Browsing to the project directory manually and running asdf.exe gives me an error saying:
**`"The program can't start because cygwin1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."`**

The same thing happens using MinGW, only a different dll is missing.
**What do I need to do to have a usable .exe?**
(I'm running Windows 7 x64 and the newest version of Eclipse and the CDT.)

EDIT:
The compiler output is as follows:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project asdf ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/asdf.cpp
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/asdf.d" -MT"src/asdf.d" -o"src/asdf.o" "../src/asdf.cpp"
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Users\Shawn\Dropbox\eclipse\asdf\Debug
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/Shawn/Dropbox/eclipse/asdf/Debug
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
Finished building: ../src/asdf.cpp

Building target: asdf.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++  -o"asdf.exe"  ./src/asdf.o   
Finished building target: asdf.exe
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This error message means that Windows isn't able to find "cygwin1.dll". The Programs that the Cygwin gcc create depend on this DLL. The file is part of cygwin , so most likely it's located in C:\cygwin\bin. To fix the problem all you have to do is add C:\cygwin\bin (or the location where cygwin1.dll can be found) to your system path. Alternatively you can copy cygwin1.dll into your Windows directory.

There is a nice tool called *DependencyWalker* that you can download from http://www.dependencywalker.com .  You can use it to check dependencies of executables, so if you inspect your generated program it tells you which dependencies are missing and which are resolved.

Comment: It worked! It needed a couple more dlls, too. So I'm assuming the only way to make standalone .exes is to use VisualStudio, then?

Comment: What I should add is that you can copy the DLLs into the same directory as the exe. The exes built by VisualStudio usualy have dependencies too, e.g. to MSVCR71.DLL

Comment: Hello. In my case, mutliple .dll are missing because my folder is called C:\cygwin64\bin. Do you think it's safe to just erase the 64 or is there a smarter way around this? Thanks

Comment: @Marco: Why don't you just add `C:\cygwin64\bin` to your system path? I guess your binary is compiled as 64bit.

Comment: @phlogratos I tried to add it to my PATH (system and user variable PATH) and it didn't work. I also copied it to `C:\` with no favorable result.

Comment: @Jossie Have you tried analyzing your problem with DependencyWalker?

Comment: @phlogratos In DependencyWalker, `CYGWIN1.DLL` is shown as red. What can I do now?

Comment: @phlogratos I typoed, forgot to add a `;` before the last folder, and also typed `C:cygwin64\bin`. The problem is now resolved.

Comment: If a program needs cygwin1.dll, does that mean it also requires a cygwin installation? Or can it run on any machine so long as the dll is present?

Comment: For me it worked when adding `cygwin1.dll` to `C:\windows` directory.

Comment: @ShawnWalton " So I'm assuming the only way to make standalone .exes is to use VisualStudio, then?" -- Why the heck would you assume that? You don't even need VS to run Microsoft's C compiler, let alone all the other compilers that run on Windows.

Comment: For me, what actually worked was adding the whole of Cygwin bin to my path for Windows 8, legacy support is a female dog...

Answer (score 2):

You can compile with either Cygwin's `g++` or MinGW (via stand-alone or using Cygwin package). However, in order to run it, you need to add the `Cygwin1.dll` (and others) PATH to the **system** Windows PATH, before any cygwin style paths.

Thus add: **`;C:\cygwin64\bin`** to the **end** of your Windows *system* `PATH` variable.

Also, to compile for use in **CMD** or **PowerShell**, you may need to use:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -static -std=c++11 prog_name.cc -o prog_name.exe
```

<sub>(This invokes the cross-compiler, if installed.)</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @not2qubit. But you forgot to put a colon in the ';C\cygwin64\bin' string, right after 'C'. I think it would be better to edit your answer. Because I was a bit confused at first. Bests ...

Comment: Hi @SANN I've now fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add to this and save someone another google, just do this in cmd:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\cygwin64\bin
```